# Aggregation json by elements of sub-json

Tags: python, json

I have the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "a-1",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "a", 
                "Key": "Type"
            }
        ], 
        "CreationDate": "2018-02-25T17:33:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Name": "a-2",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "a", 
                "Key": "Type"
            }
        ], 
        "CreationDate": "2018-02-26T17:33:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Name": "b-1",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "b", 
                "Key": "Type"
            }
        ], 
        "CreationDate": "2018-01-21T17:33:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Name": "b-2",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "b", 
                "Key": "Type"
            }
        ], 
        "CreationDate": "2018-01-22T17:33:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Name": "c-1",
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "c", 
                "Key": "Type"
            }
        ], 
        "CreationDate": "2018-08-29T17:33:19.000Z"
    }
]
```

I want to print out the oldest `Name` of each `Value` when there are more than one member in the group (This should be configurable. For example: The x oldest items when there are more than y members). In this case there are two `a`, two `b` and one `c`, So the expected result will be:

```
 a-1
 b-1
```

Here if my Python code:

```
data = ec2.describe_images(Owners=['11111'])
images = data['Images']
grouper = groupby(map(itemgetter('Tags'), images))
groups = (list(vals) for _, vals in grouper)
res = list(chain.from_iterable(filter(None, groups)))
```

Currently `res` contains only list of `Key` and `Value` and it's not grouped by. Any one can show my how to continue the code to the expected result?

Comment: Can you guarantee that there's exactly one dict with the `"Value"` key in it in each item's `Tags`?

Comment: Why no `c-1` in the result?

Comment: There is only one type of `c`. I to print out only when the group has more than 1 member.

Comment: Actually i have a huge list and i need the ability to print out the x oldest members when there are more than y members of each group. In the example above, x and y are equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using pandas, it takes a json string as input (`json_string`)

A lot of the time pandas is overkill, but here I think it will be nice because you basically want to group by value and then eliminate some groups based on criteria such as how many members they have

```
import pandas as pd

# load the dataframe from the json string
df = pd.read_json(json_string)
df['CreationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreationDate'])

# create a value column from the nested tags column
df['Value'] = df['Tags'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['Value'])

# groupby value and iterate through groups
groups = df.groupby('Value')
output = []
for name, group in groups:
    # skip groups with fewer than 2 members
    if group.shape[0] < 2:
        continue

    # sort rows by creation date
    group = group.sort_values('CreationDate')

    # save the row with the most recent date
    most_recent_from_group = group.iloc[0]
    output.append(most_recent_from_group['Name'])

print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using AWS Lambda and the package `pandas` is not available there. I didn't manage to upload it also as an external package as it too large. Is there an option to write a solution without `pandas`?

Comment: Haven't used that before, but from a search it looks like you can install pandas onto AWS lambda with this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html